# Remove tag using Asana API

Tags: asana

Is there a way to do it? I couldn't find an endpoint for that in the [documentation](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/#tags).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean deleting the tag globally? You can remove a tag from a task via `POST /tasks/task-id/removeTag`, but there isn't currently a way to delete a tag entirely.

Comment: Yeah, I mean global deletion. And you're right. I figured it's not implemented.

Comment: I still don't see a way to delete a tag in the docs. Is that still not possible?